# Changing <a> tag border-top's color in menu using jQuery FOR loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to add to my menu a colorful border-top. I know that I can do that with only HTML (by adding `style="border-top-color: red;"`), but I'm just curious to know how to do this using jQuery. 
This is what I've tried so far:

```
var colors = ['purple', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black'];
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    $("li").html("<a style= 'border-top-color: colors[i]'>");
```

I've tried also replacing the `$("li")` with `$("a")` but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly, all that will do when you get it right will create links in all lis with a black border....I do not think that is what you want.

Comment: This will change all list items 4 times. Is that really what you want?

Comment: more dislikes plesae

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you actually want is this:

```js
var colors = ['purple', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black'];
$("li a") //select all the anchors
  .each(function(index) { //loop through anchors
    var current = $(this); //current anchor being looped over
    current.css("border-top-color", colors[index]); //set the border top color based on the index
  });
```

```css
ul li {
    display: inline;  
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a { 
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you. im now more curious to know - how can i change the 1 <a> background to its border-top color? i've tried this: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mekevanawe/edit?html,css,js,output) but it marks the whole <a> backgrounds and does not go back when im "moutleave()" it.

Comment: You need to set mouseleave and set it back

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
var colors = ['purple', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black'];
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    $("li").append("<a style= 'border-top-color: "+colors[i]+"'>");
```

1. `.html` will overwrite the contents inside your li
   And the real question is why would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the structure of your html it's kind of hard. But something like:

```
$('a').css('border-top-color', 'red');
```

Should be a good start.